# Показ ProgressBar во время подгрузки данных

Tags: android

Подгружаю изображения с инета порциями (по 15 штук) и вывожу их списком. 
Новая подгрузка начинается, как только экран прокручен до последнего подгруженного изображения. Подгружаю изображения, используя AsyncTask. Хочу, чтобы пока подгружалась новая порция данных, показывался ProgressBar. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5):

[Android AsyncTask Progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157515/android-asynctask-progress-bar) (третья ссылка в гугле).

Comment: А можно, чтобы бар был не диалогом?
Хочу просто, чтобы после подгруженной порции данных появлялся progressbar, который был бы элементом списка, а не на весь экран...

Comment: сделайте элементом списка (делайте его, например, видимым в onPreExecute, и невидимым в onPostExecute, либо вообще удаляйте).

Comment: Вот у меня с этим то и проблема - не могу сделать элементом списка..

Comment: @Stas0n то есть Вы не можете создать layout с прогрессбаром? И использовать его в адаптере для создания вьюх? Или можно под списком выводить прогрессбар в основной вьюхе

Comment: Как его сделать элементом списка?
Так-то создали при подгрузке новых данных появляется progressBar, только на весь экран

Comment: У вас ListActivity или обычное Activity с листом? Если второй вариант то просто добавьте под списком прогресс бар, например и меняйте свойство видимости на View.VISIBLE, а по завершению на View.GONE

Comment: у меня ListActivity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190820/android-listactivity-how-to-add-a-view-below-the-listview